# Can not run document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I just wrote a simple javascript to submit a form.

```
<div class=login>       
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <form id="form" method="get" action="summary_iframe.html" onsubmit="return validate()">

    User: <input type="text" id="userAc" value="" name="userAc"><br>

    Password:   <input type="text" id="userPw" value="" name="userPw"><br>
```

This is the function, check that both user and password are not blank and there is no intervening space in use.

```
function validate(){
var userAc = document.getEmelentById('userAc').value;
var userPw = document.getEmelentById('userPw').value;

if(userAc.length == 0 || userPw.lenth == 0 || userAc.indexOf(' ')>-1 || userPw.indexOf(' ')>-1)


    {   
        alert("Please input again!");
        return false;
    }

else 
    {
    checkLogin(userAc, userPw);
    return true;
    }

}
```

But it does not work, I used a browser to debug and when it's running this line, it quits form the function.

```
var userAc = document.getEmelentById('userAc').value;
```

Please tell me what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `getEmelentById` is not `getElementById`, *"I used a browser to debug and when it's running this line, it quits form the function"* Yes, and if you look at the web console, it tells you exactly *why*.

Comment: You have a typo. `getEmelentById` != `getElementById`

Comment: You need to use as document.getElementById ('userAc').value, hereafter please check your browser console before you post any question here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please alter your function as below.

```
function validate(){
var userAc = document.getElementById('userAc').value;
var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw').value;

if(userAc.length == 0 || userPw.lenth == 0 || userAc.indexOf(' ')>-1 || userPw.indexOf(' ')>-1) 
    {   
        alert("Please input again!");
        return false;
    }    
else 
    {
    checkLogin(userAc, userPw);
    return true;
    }    
}
```

You need to use as document.getElementById('userAc').value, instead of document.getEmelentById('userAc').value. Hereafter please check your browser console before you post any question here. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have missed Submit Button.

```
<form id="form" method="get" action="summary_iframe.html" onsubmit="return validate()">

        User: <input type="text" id="userAc" value="" name="userAc"><br>

        Password:   <input type="text" id="userPw" value="" name="userPw"><br>
    <input type="submit"  value="submit" name="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

Comment: getEmelentById Spelling mistake